# How to use bootsfaces custom custom css fields

Tags: bootsfaces

I am trying to experiment bootsfaces custom themes capabilities.

Here is what I put in my web.xml

```
<context-param>
 <param-name>BootsFaces_THEME</param-name>
 <param-value>custom</param-value>     
</context-param>
```

Now if I use a b:commandButton from bootsfaces, the default theme is used, so my button will be blue. I had a look into the generated css code and the class used for the button is the default one, not the one I am expecting from my custom theme.

So what do I need to do to force bootsfaces to generate the html with the custom theme ?

My theme is properly loaded because if I manually put the custom css class on the browser it works.

**Edit**
I actually realised that the css did not have some default classes. For instance in the default bootstrap css files, "btn-primary" is the default class for html buttons.
I tried another bootstrap template containing this css class and it's working like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Update: Both "other" and "custom" work. I guess the problem was the incomplete theme you've been using.

<s>You've found a bug in our documentation. The correct setting is "other", not "custom".</s>

However, it's a strange bug. We've implemented some code mapping "custom" to "other", so in theory, your approach should work. I've opened [a ticket](https://github.com/TheCoder4eu/BootsFaces-OSP/issues/641) in order to investigate and fix the bug.

Thanks for reporting!